# GIT - push a directory inside project into different repo

Tags: git, module, repository

It sounds like a similar question to [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations), but it is not.

I have a project, call it iggy-project - and it has a remote repo called `iggy-project` in github.

Inside iggy-project, I have a `dist/` folder that I want to push to a different repo, call it `iggy-dist`

```
|-index.html
|-style.css
|-script.js
|-dist/
   |- index.html 
   |- style.css
```

How can I keep iggy-project pointing to iggy-project remote repo, but push everything inside dist/ into `iggy-dist`?

Bonus: Is it possible to do this (pushing iggy-dist to iggy-dist remote) every time I push to iggy-project so everything is done under one command?

Comment: This really feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) question. If you could share your goals I feel like a much better answer could be provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this easily. You could use [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) or [Git Subtree](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree). However, from experience, submodules are just a pain. They look nice at first, but they're cumbersome.

Consider your goals - why do you want to have `dist` be in another repository? Is there another way you can accomplish your goal without having two repositories?

Comment: this could be a good alternative to submodules: https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo